# MBProcessHud not loading in Alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hi I am using Alamofire for loading webservices and everything is fine, but the problem is that the MBProcessHud progress dialog is not loading!

My code is below please help me find my mistake.

### code:-

```
Alamofire.request("http://203.77.210.2/StockManger/SL/SearchProductsForTab", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseArray{(response:DataResponse<[Login]>) in

                MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode{

                    switch(statusCode){

                    case 200:

                        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                        let loginArray = response.result.value
                        self.validateResponse(result: loginArray!);
                        break

                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }

      }
```

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget asynchronous closure behaviour. you just show process hud when  responseArray returns response and hide after that. i think you should try below flow.

```
//Show before make request
 MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

Alamofire.request("http://203.77.210.2/StockManger/SL/SearchProductsForTab", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseArray{(response:DataResponse<[Login]>) in

                // Hide when closure return response

                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode{

                    switch(statusCode){

                    case 200:
                        let loginArray = response.result.value
                        self.validateResponse(result: loginArray!);
                        break

                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }

      }
```

Comment: oh forgot that let me try now